# Send a JSON string to a RESTful WS from Classic ASP

Tags: rest, asp-classic, vbscript

I am basically a noob in classic ASP and VBScript, so I would like to get some help to achieve the goal I have here. I've built a JSON string and I need to send it to a RESTful web service using VBScript. How do I do that?

I have some code, but I don't think it works:

```
strJSONToSend = JSONstr 'this is where I use my built JSON string

webserviceurl = "url here" 

Set objRequest = Server.createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0") 
objRequest.open "POST", webserviceurl, False 

objRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8" 
objRequest.setRequestHeader "CharSet", "utf-8" 
objRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", webserviceurl

Set objJSONDoc = Server.createobject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0") 
objJSONDoc.loadXml strJSONToSend 
objRequest.send objJSONDoc 

set objJSONDoc = nothing 
set objResult = nothing
```

Comment: What does not work exactly? The code seems fine-ish. No need to convert the JSON to XML though, like Nathan points out.

Comment: BTW, use `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.3.0`. XMLHTTP should not be used in server-side code.  Also are you sure you need to create that "CharSet" header, ordinarily the "Content-Type" specifies the charset of the entity body and you are already doing that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert the JSON to XML (since it's JSON and not XML and all):

```
strJSONToSend = JSONstr 'this is where I use my built JSON string

webserviceurl = "url here" 

Set objRequest = Server.createobject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0") 
objRequest.open "POST", webserviceurl, False 

objRequest.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8" 
objRequest.setRequestHeader "CharSet", "utf-8" 
objRequest.setRequestHeader "SOAPAction", webserviceurl

objRequest.send strJSONToSend

set objJSONDoc = nothing 
set objResult = nothing
```